# Como fazer um calculo de uma coluna que tenha virgula como decimal

Tags: javascript

Em uma table que tem uma das colunas que quero somar estao com virgula como decimal.

table[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como faco para somar estes valores?

No momento estou utilizando essa funcao mas nao soma os numeros depois do decimal.

```
    function sum() {
        var table = document.getElementById("table1"); 
        var sumVal = 0;
        for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++)

            sumVal = sumVal + parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML);


       var sumValTest = "Total nao incluido = " + sumVal;
        document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = sumValTest;

        console.log(sumVal);
}
```

Comment: Vc tem que substituir a vírgula por ponto.

Comment: @Sam, Voce e meu heroi... perfeito obrigado pelo syntax. Como eu faria para mudar a casa do milhares caso eu tenha um valor de 1.500,50?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: sim claro Augusto, com prazer. Sou novato aqui. Obrigado pela instrucao.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É porque você precisa substituir as vírgulas por ponto e trocar `parseInt` por `parseFloat`. As casas decimais no JavaScript são separadas por ponto.

Basta fazer um simples replace:

```
sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML.replace(",", "."));
```

Pode também remover os pontos de milhar e fazer a substituição da vírgula:

```
sumVal = sumVal + parseFloat(table.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML.replace(/\./g, "").replace(",", "."));
```