# Como extrair valores de uma coluna e separar los com uma virgula

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando ler uma columna de uma table e saparar os resultados com uma virgula.

Por exemplo:
preciso da coluna ID.
entao o resultado seria:
31, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2
[image]

tentei dessa maneira sem sucesso.

```
    function table1Id() {


            for(var i = 1; i < table.length; i++)

                var col = table[i].cells[0].innerHTML + ', ';
               document.getElementById("idTable1").innerHTML = col;   
}
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um calculo de uma coluna que tenha virgula como decimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422620/como-fazer-um-calculo-de-uma-coluna-que-tenha-virgula-como-decimal)

Comment: Nao e duplicata. Mas obrigado pela atencao.

Comment: Será melhor se você [edit] a pergunta adicionando um [mcve] mostrando como possui essa tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso seria melhor criar um array e depois converter em string com `.join(", ")`. Use `document.querySelectorALL` com o seletor `"#ID DA TABELA tr td:first-child"` para pegar todas as células da primeira coluna de cada linha:

```
function table1Id() {
   var ids = []; // cria a array
   var tabela = document.querySelectorAll("#ID_DA_TABELA tr td:first-child");
   for(var i = 1; i < tabela.length; i++){
      ids.push(tabela[i].textContent.trim()); // adiciona o texto da coluna na array
   }
   document.getElementById("idTable1").innerHTML = ids.join(", ");
}
```

> Onde tem `ID_DA_TABELA` você coloca o `id` da tabela em questão.

Comment: Oi Sam, existe algo de errado no codigo sugerido, trava tudo. Tentei consule.log() mas nada.

Comment: Como vc está declarando a variável `table`?

Comment: var table = document.getElementById("table1"); Estou sim
. Tambem tentei ate criar como object ao inves de array. sem sucesso.

O console.log diz: ids.join is not a function

Comment: Tá usando Datatables?

Comment: O usuario cria esse table diretamente no clientside pagina.

Comment: @user2916405 Se for uma tabela simples, fiz uma alteração na resposta que deve funcionar.

Comment: a variavel table está sendo tratada como uma lista. O que me parece estranho. Tenta substituir por `var table = document.getElementById('idTable1').rows`

Comment: Mas é bom debugar isso daí. Você precisa saber que objeto cada variável representa dentro da função. Coloca alguns breakpoints.

Comment: Funcionou sim obrigado. Obrigado pela sugestao de fazer debug. Descobrir como fazer isso. Mais uma vez obrigado. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia

Experimente o seguinte código:

```
<script>

function extractTableData() {
var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#idTable1 tbody tr ');
var strResult='';
Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
  var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
  var obj = {};
  obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
  obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
  strResult=strResult+obj.A+',';  
});
console.log('Result=' + strResult);
}
</script>
<table id="idTable1">
<tr>
<td>31</td><td>15/09/2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td><td>04/09/2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td><td>04/09/2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td><td>04/09/2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td><td>03/09/2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td><td>03/09/2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td><td>03/09/2019</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="saida">
</div>

<a href="javascript:extractTableData();">execute</a>
```

Naturalmente depois converta em uma função que retorne como desejar a string.
Estou simplesmente unindo os elementos com + ',' para exemplificar, mas, existem outras formas melhores e mais eficientes.

Mas, creio que está didático para compreensão da extração e unificação.

Usei como referência o exemplo citado aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885904/javascript-read-table-and-if-value-null-get-rows-data

Sucesso!

Answer (score -1):

Se tiver usando o Mysql, faça de uma forma simples e rápida.

```
select group_concat(id separator ', ') as id from tabela;
```

Doc do Mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Infelismente neste expecifico caso nao estou usando Mysql database, por isso preciso fazer-lo diretamente no userside. Mas obrigado pela informacao.

Comment: Como você não tinha informado qual banco de dados estava usando, respondi imaginando que poderia ser o Mysql. Seria melhor fazer isso no banco que pelo código.

Comment: Sim concordo com voce plenamente. Mas neste caso usuario cria toda a table diretamente no client side e depois e enviado para uma planilia do google sheets.