# Como eu busco propriedades dentro de uma td / tr usando apenas js

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-eventos, web-scraping, scraping

Boa tarde pessoal, preciso buscar dados de dentro de um site (scraping) que estão dentro de uma table, com  e . A informação que eu preciso está dentro dos td's. Segue o código:

```
 <table width="95%" class="infraTable" summary="Assuntos">
    <tr>
       <th class="infraTh">Evento</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Data/Hora</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Descrição</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Usuário</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Documentos</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrClara">
        <td>64</td>
        <td>05/09/2019 15:16:15</td>
        <td>Baixa Definitiva</td>
        <td>140274</td>
        <td> Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrEscura">
        <td>63</td>
        <td>24/06/2019 21:27:34</td>
        <td>Distribuído   Retificação ou Suprimento ou Restauração de Registro Civil <BR>Número: 00259707220198272729</td>
        <td>TO6615</td>
        <td>Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrClara">
        <td>62</td>
        <td>02/05/2019 14:55:03</td>
        <td>Juntada - Outros documentos</td>
        <td>356753</td>
        <td>Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
```

Porém, quando tento buscar pela classe da td ou pelos elementos td's, usando o document.getElement.. eu obtenho várias propriedades ( colocarei apenas algumas para que o texto não fique muito grande) que não estão no código do texto:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("td")
HTMLCollection(349)
0: td
1: td
clientWidth: 83
colSpan: 1
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
draggable: false
elementTiming: ""
enterKeyHint: ""
firstChild: text
firstElementChild: null
headers: ""
height: ""
hidden: false
id: ""
innerHTML: "24/06/2019 21:27:34"
innerText: "24/06/2019 21:27:34"
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: text
lastElementChild: null
localName: "td"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: td
nextSibling: text
noWrap: false
nodeName: "TD"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 72
offsetLeft: 49
offsetParent: table.infraTable
offsetTop: 81
offsetWidth: 83
onabort: null
onauxclick: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onformdata: null
onfullscreenchange: null
onfullscreenerror: null
ongotpointercapture: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<td>24/06/2019 21:27:34</td>"
outerText: "24/06/2019 21:27:34"
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: tr.infraTrEscura
parentNode: tr.infraTrEscura
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
prefix: null
2: td
3: td
(...)
```

As informações que eu quero, estão nessas propriedades, dentro de "innerText"ou "innerHTML"ou "outerText" ou "outerHTML". 
Não consigo pegar essas informações de jeito nenhum.
O site não usa jquery, então fica ainda mais complicado.
Queria fazer esse scraping usando apenas js, com o node. 
Preciso de uma força galera.

Comment: Você quer buscar uma informação específica ou uma linha específica?

Comment: Como você está bucando informações?

Comment: Carregue o script do JQuery, e use o poder do mesmo, caso você tenha familiaridade com as funções da biblioteca.

Comment: @adventistaam eu consigo chegar nas td's de várias formas, como Array.from(document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "td")).

Comment: @adventistaam eu queria essas informações da tabela, como no código que anexei, 
        <td>64</td>
        <td>05/09/2019 15:16:15</td>
        <td>Baixa Definitiva</td>

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus eu injetaria o jquery na página ? Como faria isso ?

Comment: Caso ajude, a página que estou tentando extrair esses dados da td, é https://consultaeproc.tjto.jus.br/eprocV2_prod_1grau/externo_controlador.php?acao=processo_seleciona_publica&acao_origem=processo_consulta_publica&acao_retorno=processo_consulta_publica&num_processo=00227512720148272729&num_chave=&num_chave_documento=&hash=27998d644bc35a42b05905694b8d190b

Comment: Então você quer uma informação específica... Com o jquery realmente seria mais fácil e tem vários exemplos

Comment: Bastaria você colocar a biblioteca antes do código javascript. JQuery são um conjunto de funções JavaScript, que visam facilitar e agilizar o desenvolvimento de sistemas.

É uma porção de código, mas minificado, antes, fica tudo certo. Talvez seja uma forma não tão eficiente do que usar javascript puro, mas é a forma mais rápida para fazer o que precisa ser feito.

Comment: Você pode intectar chamando o arquivo [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js), [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42280806/6754506) e tem um exemplo de uso com jquery

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus então eu teria que extrair o código para inserir jquery ? ou teria como fazer essa injeção sem extrair o código, para inserir a bib jquery

Comment: Por que você não consegue pegar essas informações de jeito nenhum? Se você descobriu que o dado que você precisa está dentro do atributo `innerText`, `innerHTML`, etc, é só usar essa atributo para obter a informação que você precisa. v.g. `var dado_que_eu_preciso =  document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].innerText;`. Onde `i` é a posição da `td` que você precisa.

Answer (score 2):

Oi! Da uma olhada nessa função! 
Respondi hoje sobre isso em outro questionamento, mas, acho que aplica-se ao que você está buscando.

```js
function extractTableData() {
console.log('Extraindo dados');
var myTab = document.querySelectorAll('#idTable1 tbody tr ');
var strResult='';
Array.from(myTab).forEach(input => {
  var tds = input.closest('tr').children;
  var obj = {};
  obj.A = tds[0].textContent;
  obj.B = tds[1].textContent;
  strResult=strResult+obj.A+',';  
});
console.log('Result=' + strResult);
}
```

```html
<table width="95%" id="idTable1" class="infraTable" summary="Assuntos">
    <tr>
       <th class="infraTh">Evento</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Data/Hora</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Descrição</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Usuário</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Documentos</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrClara">
        <td>64</td>
        <td>05/09/2019 15:16:15</td>
        <td>Baixa Definitiva</td>
        <td>140274</td>
        <td> Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrEscura">
        <td>63</td>
        <td>24/06/2019 21:27:34</td>
        <td>Distribuído   Retificação ou Suprimento ou Restauração de Registro Civil <BR>Número: 00259707220198272729</td>
        <td>TO6615</td>
        <td>Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrClara">
        <td>62</td>
        <td>02/05/2019 14:55:03</td>
        <td>Juntada - Outros documentos</td>
        <td>356753</td>
        <td>Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    
</table>    
   <button type="button" onclick="extractTableData()">Extrair</button>
```

Questão similar, que falei:
[Como extrair valores de uma coluna e separar los com uma virgula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/422666/como-extrair-valores-de-uma-coluna-e-separar-los-com-uma-virgula/422698#422698)

Sucesso, 
Valeu!

Comment: Valleeu @Valmor. Eu tentei aqui, mas me retornou undefined

Comment: Note que eu mudei um pouco tua tabela, coloquei um nome / id na tabela  id="idTable1"

Answer (score 0):

Pra ler o conteúdo de uma `td`, você pode usar a propriedade `innerText`:

```js
var tabela = document.querySelector(".infraTable");
var tds = tabela.getElementsByTagName("td");

for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++)
{
    console.log("Conteudo da coluna " + i + " é " + tds[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<table width="95%" class="infraTable" summary="Assuntos">
    <tr>
       <th class="infraTh">Evento</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Data/Hora</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Descrição</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Usuário</th>
       <th class="infraTh">Documentos</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrClara">
        <td>64</td>
        <td>05/09/2019 15:16:15</td>
        <td>Baixa Definitiva</td>
        <td>140274</td>
        <td> Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrEscura">
        <td>63</td>
        <td>24/06/2019 21:27:34</td>
        <td>Distribuído   Retificação ou Suprimento ou Restauração de Registro Civil <BR>Número: 00259707220198272729</td>
        <td>TO6615</td>
        <td>Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="infraTrClara">
        <td>62</td>
        <td>02/05/2019 14:55:03</td>
        <td>Juntada - Outros documentos</td>
        <td>356753</td>
        <td>Evento não gerou documento(s)</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

Note que, primeiro selecionei a tabela, em seguida obtive todas as TDs e fui percorrendo uma a uma com o comando `for` e usando o `innerText` para pegar o conteúdo. É possível filtrar por linha, por uma columa em específico, basta aproveitar esse exemplo.